# What is the best way to isolate .ToListAsync()?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I have a Blazor App which uses EntityFrameworkCore and a Generic repository.

In my Services I query the repository, but when I try to call .ToListAsync(); - it requires that I add - using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
This means it will create a dependency to EF. I don't want to bind my service to EF.

.ToListAsync() is an extension method.
What is the best way to isolate the Service from it? I achieved it through an additional wrapper class - AsyncConverter. Is there a better way?

```
public class AsyncConverter : IAsyncConverter
{
    public Task<List<TSource>> ConvertToListAsync<TSource>(IQueryable<TSource> source, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return source.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}

public class EfRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class
{
    public EfRepository(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        this.Context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        this.DbSet = this.Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    protected DbSet<TEntity> DbSet { get; set; }

    protected ApplicationDbContext Context { get; set; }

    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> All() => this.DbSet;
}




public class ItemsDataService : IItemsDataService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Item> _itemsRepository;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IAsyncConverter _asyncConverter;
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<Errors> _localizer;


    public ItemsDataService(IRepository<Item> itemsRepository, 
        IMapper mapper,
        IAsyncConverter asyncConverter,
        IStringLocalizer<Errors> localizer = null)
    {
        _itemsRepository = itemsRepository;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _asyncConverter = asyncConverter;
        _localizer = localizer;
    }

    public async Task<Response<IEnumerable<ItemNameDto>>> GetItemsNamesAsync(string searchWord, string userId)
    {
        try
        {
            searchWord.ThrowIfNull();
            userId.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty();

            var query = _itemsRepository.All()
                .Where(x => x.UserId == userId);

            var names = new List<ItemNameDto>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchWord))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchWord.ToLower()));
            }

            var queryProjection = _mapper.ProjectTo<ItemNameDto>(query); **/*.ToListAsync(); - This would add a dependency to EntityFrameworkCore. That it why I introduced AsyncConverter*/**
            names = await _asyncConverter.ConvertToListAsync(queryProjection);

            var response = ResponseBuilder.Success<IEnumerable<ItemNameDto>>(names);
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var response = ResponseBuilder.Failure<IEnumerable<ItemNameDto>>("An error occured while getting items names.");
            return response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "This means it will create a dependency to EF." -- what? The reference is there in your "fix" as well, you just have an additional non-standard function call to make parsing your code more difficult. What are you trying to achieve? Use EF without using EF function names?

Comment: You don't need to isolate it because it's a data access concern, and your service layer should not be dealing with data access. Instead you should build up the query in your service layer and pass it down to your repository layer, where you execute said query and materialise it via `ToListAsync`, and simply return the materialised `List<Entity>` to the service layer. Any mapping then happens in the service layer.

Comment: @Blindy The point is that `IAsyncConverter` can be mocked, while EF Core's `EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions` (which defines `ToListAsync` as an extension method) cannot be.

Comment: Sure it can, C# overload resolution rules clearly state that member functions take precedence over extension methods. So add that function to your mocked list object and you're set.

Comment: @Blindy What I am trying to achieve is not bind the Service with EF. That is why I introduced AsyncConverter as a "fix". My question is: is there a better way than what I have done to use .toListAsync() and not bind the Service layer with EF?

Comment: @IanKemp, what you are suggesting is basically to transfer the method ConvertToListAsync to the generic repository?

Comment: The better way is the opposite of what are you asking - get rid of repository, take dependency on EF Core and use  `DbContext` and `DbSet`s directly. EF Core provides UOW / Repository for you, and by hiding them you just lose control and useful extension methods with no real benefits.

Comment: My usual approach is to put all the query-building code in my repositories, and have them return a materialized result. So I can mock the repository layer when unit-testing my services class. Trying to unit-test the data access layer can be fraught. If you prefer building your queries in the service layer, Ian Kemp's approach can work, basically putting your ConvertToListAsync method into the EfRepository class and its interface instead of having a whole new service to inject.

Comment: If you return IQueryable in your repository - it is not real repository but just not needed wrapper which means additional memory usage and boilerplate. Add abstractions only when they are really needed and this you will know only after writing some code in your project. If you need reusable methods - just create extensions.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, after trying several approaches with the project, I believe your approach is probably the best. I moved the whole quering in the [repository](https://github.com/MiBuena/ListGeneratorAsync/blob/main/ListGeneration.Data/Repositories/ItemsRepository.cs) layer and now I use ToListAsync() there directly. If you wish, you can summarize this and post it as an official answer, so that I can choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My usual approach is to put all the query-building code in my repositories, and have them return a materialized result. So I can mock the repository layer when unit-testing my services class.

Trying to unit-test the data access layer can be fraught, since it's inherently designed to be an integration layer. Queries that work one way when you are using in-memory objects may have different behavior when they're translated by Entity Framework.

If you prefer building your queries in the service layer, Ian Kemp's approach can work, basically putting your `ConvertToListAsync` method into the `EfRepository` class and its interface instead of having a whole new service to inject.